# POST превращается в GET

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, get

Есть ajax запрос. В нем явно указано, что он должен обрабатываться методом post. Тем не менее форма обрабатывается методом get. Как это можно исправить. Код:

```
<form id="formx">
    <select name="category">
        <option value="Global news">Global news</option>
        <option value="Technical News">Technical News</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Название статьи" required><br/>
    <input type="shortcontent" name="short" placeholder="Краткое содержание"><br/>
    <textarea name="content" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Текст статьи"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Создать" name="create"><br/>
    </form>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formx').submit(function(){
            var msg = $('#formx').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'admin/createNews',
          data: msg,
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
          },
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Проект разрабатывается на laravel

Comment: попробуй написать POST

Comment: Скорее всего не хватает заголовка `Accept: application/json`, поэтому когда вы отправляете POST вы вероятнее всего упираетесь в валидацию, которая вместо того что б вернуть 422 с JSON редиректит вас на html c описание ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Пару правок

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formx').submit(function(e){ /* добавить "е" */
            var msg = $('#formx').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'admin/createNews',
          data: msg,
          /* dataType: 'JSON', либо убрать либо приводить msg к json Виду */ 
          success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
          },
        });
        e.preventDefault(); /* добавить */
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Так даже гетом не отправляется

Comment: @Антон данные передаются в "admin/createNews"?